# Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04 not suspend when inactive

Tags: suspend, hp

Suspending is working properly when I do manually or set time for inactive shorter than turning screen off timer but I want to turn screen off earlier and suspend the machine after 1-2 hours but it's not working. My machine is HP probook 450 G2.

Answer (score 0):

These are two settings that you configure in different places. Open the control panel, selecting `System Settings` in the cog applet (where you power off the PC):

- to set the time before suspend, go to `Power`
- to set the time before screen blanks, go to `Brightness & Lock`

Comment: I have done this but nothing happend. Only screen turn off and the machine continue to work without suspending.

Comment: Is you PC plugged to power? Are you using the same amount of time for `On battery power` and `When plugged in`? Also, use a small amount of time for testing purposes: using 1-2 hours makes it difficult to test.

Comment: Set the same amount of time for both but I think the main problem is turning screen off (Brightness & Lock). When this occur the other timer just turn on the screen but nothing happend.